# Segmentation fault (core dumped) while trying to get values from csv to array of struct

Tags: c

```
#define MAXROW 30

typedef struct emp_info {
    int emp_id;
    char *name;
    char *dept;
    int salary;
} emp_info;

void store(emp_info *data,  char *filename);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int preceding;
    int following;
    emp_info data[MAXROW] ;
    // emp_info data[MAXROW] = {{.salary = 0 }};
    char *filename = "dat/emp_info.csv";
    store(data,filename);
    return 0;
}


void store(emp_info emp_arr[],  char *filename)
{
    size_t n = 0;
    char  *line;
    FILE *csv_stream;
    if((csv_stream = fopen(filename,"r")) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"file open for reading failed. exit!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ( n < MAXROW && (fgets(line,sizeof line, csv_stream)) != NULL)
    {   
        emp_info tmp;
        if(sscanf(line,"%d,%29[^,],%29[^,],%d",
            &tmp.emp_id,tmp.name,tmp.dept,&tmp.salary) != 4)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"error: failed to parse string.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        emp_arr[n++] = tmp;
    }

    if(fclose(csv_stream) == EOF)
        perror("stream error-csv_stream.");
}
```

ERROR: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
Idea is trying to get values from csv file(less than 10 rows) to array of struct emp_info.
code link: https://godbolt.org/z/h5h1K11T6

update

---

emp_info.csv :

```
1,alice,depa,1000
2,bob,depa,2000
3,carol,depb,1501
4,david,depa,1200
5,ed,depc,1306
```

After fix segment fault, now the issue is parse csv content. Now the error is fail to parse string.
I feel like my sscanf pattern should work. But it doesn't.

I also tried:

```
  if(sscanf(line,"%d,%19[^,],%19[^,],%d\n",
        &tmp.emp_id,tmp.name,tmp.dept,&tmp.salary) != 4)
```

But still cannot parse csv content.

Comment: Now seems like a *very* good time to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. More specifically how to use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to catch crashes as and when they happen, and locate where in your code it happens, and examine all involved variables at the time of the crash to see their values.

Comment: A big hint though: `fgets(line,sizeof line, csv_stream)`? Where is `line` pointing? What is its size?

Comment: Just a tip... When you get it working, the function name might be better if it were `load()` rather than `store()`... More conventional to think of "loading data from file" and "storing data to file"...

Comment: @Fe2O3 thanks. Now the problem is  the sscanf issue, can you spare  sometime check it.

Comment: Sorry, no. @Someprogrammerdude told you were to begin to solve this problem. "Where is line pointing?" You cannot `sscanf( )` from somewhere unknown. In fact, you cannot `fgets( )` to that unknown space either (without creating havoc.) Explain the code to your rubber duck, slowly and methodically... Pay attention to hints given by people...

Comment: And, when you have resolved the issue of the `line` pointer, you'll have the exact same one repeated (twice) with the `tmp.name` and `tmp.dept` pointers.

Answer (score 0):

refactored code:

```
#define MAXROW 30
#define MAXC 50

typedef struct emp_info {
    int emp_id;
    char name[MAXC];
    char dept[MAXC];
    int salary;
} emp_info;

size_t load(emp_info emp_arr[],  char *filename);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int preceding;
    int following;
    emp_info data[MAXROW] = {{.emp_id = 0}};

    char *filename = "dat/emp_info.csv";
    size_t real_size = load(data,filename);

    for(int j = 0; j < real_size; j++){
        if (data[j].emp_id == 0) 
            break;

        printf("%d\t%s\t%s\t%d\n",data[j].emp_id,data[j].name,data[j].dept,data[j].salary);
    }
    printf("size of data: %lu\n", sizeof data / sizeof *data);

    return 0;
}


size_t load(emp_info emp_arr[],  char *filename)
{
    size_t n = 0;
    char  line[MAXC] = {0};

    FILE *csv_stream;
    if((csv_stream = fopen(filename,"r")) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"file open for reading failed. exit!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ( n < MAXROW && (fgets(line,sizeof line, csv_stream)) != NULL)
    {   
        emp_info tmp;
        if(sscanf(line,"%d,%[^,],%[^,],%d",
            &tmp.emp_id,tmp.name,tmp.dept,&tmp.salary) != 4)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"error: failed to parse string.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        emp_arr[n++] = tmp;
    }
    

    if(fclose(csv_stream) == EOF)
        perror("stream error-csv_stream.");
    
    return n;

}
```